# change cell colour when opening workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to change the colour of two cells (C3:C4) to red every time my workbook is opened.

The code I have tried is in my Workbook_Open event but I'm getting *Application-defined or object-defined error*. Here is the code:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

Worksheets("Balance Sheet").Range("C3:C4").Interior.Color = vbRed

End Sub
```

Is my syntax wrong or is it more that this can't be done during the workbook_open? And how can I correct it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, it appears I was getting the error because I was trying to edit a locked sheet. Added lines to unlock and lock and it works fine.

Slightly embarrassing but lesson learned for next time.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that your worksheet is called "Balance Sheet". Any typo would make Excel to not find and return an error.

Comment: Thanks, this was one of the first things I checked, definitely no typo there.

Comment: Alternatively one can rename the names of the worksheets, so one can work with wsBalanceSheet.Range... instead of Table1.Range or Worksheets("Balance Sheet")...

Answer (score 0):

As you wrote its not a typo.
So please check if makros are enabled in the excel file. In the default configuration makros are blocked and therefore nothing happens. Your code is working...

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Enable-or-disable-macros-in-Office-files-12b036fd-d140-4e74-b45e-16fed1a7e5c6

Comment: Macros are enabled, I have some code in the SelectionChange event that is working fine.

Comment: Thats strange. I even tested it and it works as expected... Maybe try to use the worksheet name instead of the Worksheets("Balance Sheet").

Comment: Thanks Stefan. In my project Explorer the sheet is labelled as Sheet1(Balance Sheet). Would I use

Comment: Yes, just try Sheet1.Range. You are able to rename this in the properties window, just use a name that is more descriptive.